# Check a discontinuity of a function

Tags: calculus

Check discontinuity of a function 
$$  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x\left\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor,  & x\neq 0 \\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)\neq f(0)\Rightarrow$$removable discontinuity at $x=0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You should verify that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)$ actually exists, and is something other than $f(0) = 0$. Also, there are other discontinuities that you seemed to have missed.

Comment: Try computing the limit along the sequence $x_n = \frac{1}{n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any positive integer $n,$ $f(1/n)=f(-1/n)=1.$ Note further that $f$ is increasing on $\left(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n\right]$ and decreasing (and continuous) on $\left(-\frac1n,-\frac1{n+1}\right].$

Determine $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sup_{-\frac1{n+1}<x\le-\frac1n}f(x)\right)$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\inf_{\frac1n<x\le\frac1{n+1}}f(x)\right),$$ and use this to determine whether or not you are correct.